# How to run Ignite with defined JVM heap

Tags: jvm, ignite, jvm-hotspot, jvm-arguments, gridgain

Currently Ignite is taking the default installed OpenJDK 11 JVM heap size. Now, I want to define the JVM initial and max heap size for Ignite Instance. Where exactly I need to define so that it will take the defined JVM heap config to run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use -Xms, -Xmx to set JVM memory parameters.

Here is more information: https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/jvm-and-system-tuning
  and: https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/preparing-for-production

JDK 11 specific: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15523_01/web.1111/e13814/jvm_tuning.htm#PERFM160

In the Ignite logs you could see how much memory was allocated along with other parameters: look for these lines:

```
[IgniteKernal] Language runtime: Java Platform API Specification ver. 11 

[IgniteKernal] VM information: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 11.0.4+10-LTS Oracle 
Corporation Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 11.0.4+10-LTS

[IgniteKernal] VM total memory: 1.0GB

[IgniteKernal] VM arguments: [-Xms1g, -Xmx1g, ...
```

Comment: thanks for the information but I asked where I need to define these JVM parameters. If possible share me a sample config.

Comment: you can set the parameters when starting java ... i.e. java -Xmx1G -Xms1G myclass 

or start ignite like so: ignite.bat -J-Xms2G -J-Xmx2G (here you are allocating 2G)

also see : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14763079/what-are-the-xms-and-xmx-parameters-when-starting-jvm